# Application update rejected on Google Play

Tags: android, google-play

The Android app is on the Google Play Store.It is getting all its context from a web site that its main job is reviewing movies. The update version got rejected from Google Play, 
**REASON FOR REJECTION:** ***Violation of the intellectual property and impersonation or deceptive behavior provisions of the Content Policy.***

---

After my replay where I explain that any change made in the app will lead to confusion about the site's connection with the app, and that all the content is important for me to use, They replied with this message: ***After re-reviewing your application we have found that your application uses one or more protected images that belongs to a third party (Copyrighted Movie Posters).  If you are authorized to use this content, please attach a verifiable proof of permission in reply to this email.***

---

I can give them a document about me being authorized to develop the app for the site, but the owner of the site doesn't have any authorizations or legal rights to use the movie posters.

---

We have an IOS app working just fine on the App Store, using the same data(movie posters) that the Android app is using.

---

Did anybody have this problem with an update on google play? Is there any way around it maybe? Or can somebody show me how the document should look like? Or maybe where can they buy the copyrights? But I'm not sure they will like the last one.(*again, I already have a published version of the app on the market* I guess the bot only checks the code when update? Ridiculous)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about the terms and conditions of a distribution channel, not programming.

Comment: Well I understand @CommonsWare its not, but its all about Android programming  , IF android programmers are not allowed to publish their work, what is the whole point. Somebody will recognize this to be very useful, because one can't find anything anywhere about this issue.

Comment: [Customer support questions regarding app stores are off-topic for Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic). There are many [Android developer support sites](http://www.andglobe.com) on the Internet, and your line of inquiry may be on-topic for one of those sites.

Comment: I guess I'm being rejected again

Comment: @kinsell03 Did you solve the issue with posters on screenshots? I have similar issue and also have all the documents about copyrights. I just do not know where I have to put that documents in Dev. Console to show all of that to Google Play Team.

Comment: Did anyone solve this issuse? I have published an app that got rejected because I have movie posters in the screenshots. But I se there are plenty of other apps that also do that, but how do they do that? Where can I get the documentation I need? And where do I put it?

If this is the wrong place to ask, can someone please point me in the right direction (link)?